# Flagging discrepancies from 2 different lists

Tags: list, loops

I'm trying to basically have 2 lists that at one point, were copies and are now no longer exact copies. For context, originally one was a copy made in ~2012 and I want to compare it to the original that is up to date i.e 2020.

I have a general idea about how I will go about this but I've tried researching ways to have two lists read and then when a discrepancy is found, it's flagged and a human then updates it. I am familiar with lists but it seems not enough to write a piece of python to compare the two lists side-by-side.

Any comments on either what I should be looking for in terms of concepts or where to find them would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply flag repetitive elements, you could loop throught one list  while checking if its elements appear in the other list. If that is true, you could flag them by addind their index to a third list, and then delete the elements of the first list (the list from witch you took the indexes) by iterating over the list with the indexes.

Another way would be using sets (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), but i'm new to sets so I can't quite understand them.

I hope that this would be useful. Cheers.